# Perform CURL only if last CURL is more than 10s ago

Tags: c, curl, time

I have this procedure in a smartmeter daemon to log a counter of gas consumption:

```
void http_post(const char *vzuuid) {

sprintf(url, "http://%s:%d/%s/data/%s.json?ts=%llu", vzserver, vzport, vzpath, vzuuid, unixtime());

CURL *curl;
CURLcode curl_res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) 
{
    FILE* devnull = NULL;
    devnull = fopen("/dev/null", "w+");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, DAEMON_NAME " " DAEMON_VERSION ); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, devnull);

        if( (curl_res = curl_easy_perform(curl)) != CURLE_OK) {
        syslog(LOG_INFO, "HTTP_POST(): %s", curl_easy_strerror(curl_res) );
        }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose ( devnull );

}

curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

I want to execute this only if the last call is more than 10s ago. I Thought of a global variable last_time to remember the last timestamp and to compare it with the actual timestamp in an if ... then construct around all that curl stuff. For that the direct use of unixtime() should be buffered in another variable current_time to be used to be compared with last_time.

Can anybody help me please? I am not used to use C...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good. You can do something like this:

```
#include <time.h>

void http_post(const char *vzuuid)
{ 
  static time_t last_time = 0;
  time_t cur_time;

  cur_time = time(NULL);
  if (cur_time - last_time < 10)
    return; /* nothing to do */

  last_time = cur_time;

  /* ... */
}
```

I do not use a global, but a static variable, to hold the last time of last request.

Comment: You're welcome - it was not that hard,  I just translated in C what you already said =)